# Append a txt file in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am Creating a txt file in.Net with the help of below code.

```
StreamWriter writerVer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Version.txt");                    
writerVer.WriteLine("Version : " + Context.Parameters["ver"]);                  
File.SetAttributes(@"C:\Version.txt", FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Then I need to Update the file on the next line by keeping the above code as it is.

This code overrites the entire file.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Version.txt");
writer.WriteLine("Connection string : "+con);
```

Regrads,

Sachin K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 StreamWriter writerVer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Version.txt", true);
```

There is an overload of the `StreamWriter` constructor that takes an additional `bool` parameter to indicate if you want to append or not.

Answer (score 4):

Use the constructor which takes the `append` boolean parameter to indicate whether to append to the file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("file.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use the static helper methods: [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) or [`File.AppendText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx).

Note that the latter actually returns a `StreamWriter` instance, so you'll need to close it before proceeding otherwise you're relying on the GC to do it for you.